# Configure Synchrony with Httpd

Tags: apache, proxy, httpd.conf, confluence

We want to upgrade our Confluence to [6.0](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-6-0-release-notes-844235309.html#Confluence6.0ReleaseNotes-Getreadytoupgrade) that is released in November. There is new feature *Collaborative editing* that requires *Synchrony*.
In [Proxying Atlassian server applications with Apache HTTP Server (mod_proxy_http)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_http-806032611.html): "Applications that use Synchrony, e.g. Confluence 6.0 must use Apache 2.4 and up."

1. Do this mean that I can use Apache 2.2 if I do not want to turn on Coloborative editing?
   And in [Proxying Atlassian server applications with Apache HTTP Server (mod_proxy_ajp](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/proxying-atlassian-server-applications-with-apache-http-server-mod_proxy_ajp-830284354.html)) I did not find anything about Synchrony configuration.
2. Can I configure Confluence to work via AJP if I use Synchrony?
   And where can I find example to configure Synchrony via AJP?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, meaning: You can install Confluence 6.0.x in an Apache 2.2-environment, start it and then simply disable *Collaborative Editing* in Confluence's administration.
   However, it is obviously not possible to disable Synchrony itself, but that does not hurt in any way.
   The Apache 2.4-proxy-configuration for Synchrony is explained in the document you mentioned in Part B, section 2.
2. Yes: The AJP-configuration for Confluence is not affected by Synchrony.
   As far as I am aware of, AJP and Synchrony is neither possible nor necessary.